# Value of $ \frac{a^2 + b^2 + c^2}{ac^2 - ab^2} $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

If  $a + b + c = 0$ , then value of $ \frac{a^2 + b^2 + c^2}{ac^2 - ab^2} $ is?

According to me if $ a + b + c = 0$, then $a + b = -c$

> This implies $ (a + b)^2 = c^2$
>
> This implies $a^2 + b^2 = c^2 - 2ab$

Putting this value in  $ \frac{a^2 + b^2 + c^2}{ac^2 - ab^2} $ we get

> $ \frac {c^2 - 2ab + c^2}{ac ^ 2 - ab}  = \frac {2c^2 - 2ab}{a(c^2 - b)} $
> But I'm stuck after this. Am I right in the above steps, if yes, then how should I continue?

Comment: Are these numbers integers or reals? Cause in the general case if they are reals it does not have a numeric single result. On the other hand if they are integers and we know that the quotient have to be integer too it might have,

Comment: They are real and it does not need to have only one solution.

Comment: The denominator of your last equation appears to be wrong; should it not be read: $ac^2-ab^2$?

Comment: Then the answer would be too obvious but it is not so :(

Answer (score 1):

Note that in the denominator
$$ ac^2-ab^2=a(c+b)(c-b)=a^2(b-c)$$
for further simplification. Actually, since $a$ plays a special role in the original expresion, I suggest to simply eliminate $a$ by replacing it with $-(b+c)$ throughout, e.g.
$$\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{ac^2-ab^2}=\frac{2(b^2+bc+c^2)}{(b+c)(b^2-c^2)} $$

Answer (score 0):

Put $a=-(b+c)$ we have  after   simplification 
$$
\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{ac^2-ab^2}=2\,{\frac {{c}^{2}+cb+{b}^{2}}{ \left( c+b \right)  \left( -{c}^{2}+{b
}^{2} \right) }}=2 \frac{b^3-c^3}{(b^2-c^2)^2}
$$